# How to control the number of gridview widget columns dynamically in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

I am using gridview for a report which can have up to 30 question columns. Now currently for the reports I have, there are empty ("not set columns ") for a lot of rows.
My question is how do i control the number of gridcolumns shown on the page based on a dynamic number?
Or is it possible to not show a grid columns in which the function returns null?

Comment: do your research start implementing and add a question where you get stuck, SO is no coding facility that provides you complete solutions for such broad questions

Comment: [DataProviderInterface::getModels()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-dataproviderinterface#getModels()-detail) is probably something you would want to start your research with.

Comment: Each column has a property ‘visible’ which can be dynamically set eg ‘visible’ => isset($model->paramName),

Answer (score 0):

First of all, GridView accepts configuration parameters as an array, including the columns, thus you can customize it according to your needs.

```
$gridColumns = [];
// let's say you have columns 'co1', 'col2', 'col3'
if ($showCol1) {
  /**
   * have it as an array like ['attribute' => 'col1', 'property' => value] 
   * for more customization
   */
  $gridColumns[] = 'col1'; 
}

// insert other if/else logic here

GridView::widget([
  // ...
  'columns' => $gridColumns,
  // ...
]);
```

You can check the official documentation as well as the code repository for more details. Basically, GridView is customizable, and can be somewhat dynamic if you need it to be.